# Limits on Docker hub for number of repositories

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am Using Docker from past a week and was creating some new repositories on Dockerhub. Is there any limit to create number of repositories on Dockerhub?

Comment: there is no limit for public images

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A repository can have any number of image tags. There is no stated limit for size. In practice, if an image layer gets much larger than 10 or 20 gigabytes, you may experience problems with push and pull. Your mileage may vary.

There is no limit for builds or tags for public images. (This can be changed over a period of time)

As long as you wanted to play around docker public repository will do. But, if you are looking for a private repository I would recommend hosting your own binary repository managers JFfrog or Nexus to maintain all kinds of artifacts including docker images.

Source: https://forums.docker.com/t/does-docker-hub-have-a-size-limitation-on-repos-or-images/10154

**UPDATE 2**

Inactive images are defined as images that have not been pulled or pushed in 6 months. Starting November 1, 2020:

1. Free accounts may retain inactive images for up to 6 months
2. Anonymous users will have an upper limit of 100 image pulls in a six hour period
3. Authenticated users will have an upper limit of 200 image pulls in a six hour period

A pull is defined as up to two GET requests to the registry URL path ‘/v2/*/manifests/*’.

**PS:** It is all about the policies set by the Docker, Inc. It can change over time.

Comment: You can now use GitHub container images (`ghor.io`) as well (for private/public images). See this: https://github.blog/2021-06-21-github-packages-container-registry-generally-available/

Comment: @CypherX, the domain name is ghcr.io for GitHub container repo.

Comment: @Feriman: Thank you for the correction [`ghcr.io`: GitHub Container Registry]. Unfortunately, SO does not allow anyone to update the comments beyond some time right after the comment is made.